# Android WebView scrollbar is a black rectangle

Tags: android, webview, scrollbar

Why does the WebView scrollbar render as a black rectangle?  It's as if the underlying scrollbar graphic isn't being loaded and the entire scrollbar area just ends up being black.  I'm loading static HTML.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: black scroll bar]

Here's what I believe it should look like:

[image: correct scroll bar]

Here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/initial_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String html = "";
        for(int i=0; i<250; i++) {
            html += "text"+i+" ";
        }
        WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.initial_webview);
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I'm using SDK 21 and minSDK 16, as well as a Samsung Galaxy S3 profile with API 17, if that helps.

Comment: I also have this issue. It's on pre-kitkat versions only for me.

Comment: Actually, only on KitKat it's fine, on Lollipop I can't see any scrollbar.